# mongo query - SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in my collection.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5755b94abcfc6666d6f5fe56"),
"NAME" : John Smith,
"PHONE" : "800-555-1000",
"DOC" : {
    " TYPE" : "M",
    " DATE" : "01/28/2016",
    " AMOUNT" : 281593
},
"ADDRESS" : 123 Sesame Street
```

I am trying to find this record by passing in the keys and values:

```
db.acris.find("DOC" : {" TYPE" : "MTGE"," DATE" : "01/28/2003"," AMOUNT" : 281593})
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

How can I fix this query so that the code will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is fixed as [KRONWALLED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37732109/1066031) answer shows. The query I think you want is however is:

```
db.acris.find({"DOC.TYPE" : "M", "DOC.DATE" : "01/28/2003"," DOC.AMOUNT" : 281593})
```

Notice the DOT notation for matching against subfields.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing {} around the whole find like

`db.collection.find({ "DOC" : ... })`

Update:
Just to be complete. You can also search for the whole element. You don't necessarily need dot notation.

```
> db.test.insertOne({"NAME" : "John Smith",
... "PHONE" : "800-555-1000",
... "DOC" : {
...     " TYPE" : "M",
...     " DATE" : "01/28/2016",
...     " AMOUNT" : 281593
... },
... "ADDRESS" : "123 Sesame Street"})

> db.test.find({"DOC" : { " TYPE" : "M", " DATE" : "01/28/2016", " AMOUNT" : 281593 }})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5759a933cdcc5a8d09a1aeb9"), "NAME" : "John Smith", "PHONE" : "800-555-1000", "DOC" : { " TYPE" : "M", " DATE" : "01/28/2016", " AMOUNT" : 281593 }, "ADDRESS" : "123 Sesame Street" }
```